# Have tree hide gitignored files

Tags: git, tree

Is there a way to make `tree` not show files that are ignored in `.gitignore`?

Comment: If you really want to consider all possible ignored files, try to parse the output of [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might help: list `git` ignored files in an almost-compatible way for `tree` filter:

```
function tree-git-ignore {
    # tree respecting gitignore

    local ignored=$(git ls-files -ci --others --directory --exclude-standard)
    local ignored_filter=$(echo "$ignored" \
                    | egrep -v "^#.*$|^[[:space:]]*$" \
                    | sed 's~^/~~' \
                    | sed 's~/$~~' \
                    | tr "\\n" "|")
    tree --prune -I ".git|${ignored_filter: : -1}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Another way is possible if you're using [tree 1.8.0](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/tree.1.html)
since it supports the `--fromfile` flag:

> **`--fromfile`**
>
>   Reads a directory listing from a file
>   rather than the file-system. 
>   Paths provided on the command
>   line are files to read from rather than directories to search. 
>   The dot (
>   **`.`**
>   )  directory  indicates  that  tree
>   should read paths from standard input.

We could use `git ls-tree` to get all non-git-ignored files in a project, and pipe the output to `tree`.

Assuming we have a git repository, where `ignored` files are ignored in `.gitignore`:

```
git_repo
├── .gitignore
├── bar
│   ├── b.txt
│   └── ignored
├── foo
│   ├── a.txt
│   └── ignored
└── ignored
```

The following command:

```bash
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | tree --fromfile
```

Gives:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── bar
│   └── b.txt
└── foo
    └── a.txt

2 directories, 3 files
```

Or if you need a specific path:

```bash
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD foo | tree --fromfile
```

Gives:

```
.
└── a.txt

0 directories, 1 file
```

### Caveats

- **Beware** that changes such as deleted or renamed files that haven't already been committed can cause `git ls-tree` to appear out of sync.

Answer (score 11):

[Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) respects `.gitignore` (and some other 'ignore' files) by default and can be used as an alternative to git commands. The difference is that all files (except hidden files) are listed even if they haven't been commited to version control yet:

```
rg --files | tree --fromfile
```

This can be used to create a shell function that sorts directories first and allows for more flexible usage (specifying the directory path and adding ripgrep flags):

```
rg,tree() { rg --files $@|tree --fromfile --dirsfirst }
```

Requires tree > 1.8 as pointed out in another answer.

Comment: +1 for Ripgrep if you can get it. I like this solution as it's more elegant, presumably faster, and aligns better with expected behavior in comparison to my answer.

Comment: This answer ignores "hidden" (for example files that start with '.') files tracked by git. Fortunately, it's easily modified to fix this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691245/185953

Answer (score 10):

Tree supports the `-I` flag.

> `-I pattern`
>
>   Do not list those files that match the wild-card pattern.

Tree supports a single pattern which will exclude all files/directories that match it.

Git's ignore files are a bit more complicated:

Exclusion can come from multiple files,  `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`, the output of `git config --get core.excludesfile` , `.gitignore` (per directory), `~/.gitignore`, and more (see `man gitignore`).

Another problem is the patterns that `tree` supports differs from what git does (as noted by @Brad Urani).

But we can get close-ish ...

```
tree -I "$(grep -hvE '^$|^#' {~/,,$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/}.gitignore|sed 's:/$::'|tr \\n '\|')"
```

Or as a function:

```
function gtree {
    git_ignore_files=("$(git config --get core.excludesfile)" .gitignore ~/.gitignore)
    ignore_pattern="$(grep -hvE '^$|^#' "${git_ignore_files[@]}" 2>/dev/null|sed 's:/$::'|tr '\n' '\|')"
    if git status &> /dev/null && [[ -n "${ignore_pattern}" ]]; then
      tree -I "${ignore_pattern}" "${@}"
    else 
      tree "${@}"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Nice! Am I correct that the fact that this is not removing comment lines from .gitignore will cause problems?

Comment: I guess it's also not going to respect .gitignore files outside the home dir 

Comment: @BradUrani - i've updated my answer to use `git` commands to try find the file. What that returns will depend on what setting you have.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I think because my `~/.gitignore` is a symlink. I've been trying to find a way to rely on `git` to tell me what's ignored, but all my efforts to find the right combination keep running into difficulties or ambiguous situations.

Comment: Also it looks like `tree -I` does respect all the globbing options that `.gitignore` does which makes me think there's no perfect solution. Best approximation I came up with last night is
`echo "node_modules|tmp|_build" > ~/.treeignore` and `tree -I "$(cat ~/.treeignore)"`

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if your `.gitignore` has directories with a trailing slash. Adding `sed 's_/|_|_g'` to the end of the `grep` pipeline fixed it for me.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. Just one question: If the global gitignore file is _not_ ~/.gitignore, the script will output `grep: <home>/.gitignore: No such file or directory` - how do I use a different filename?

Answer (score 6):

tree has a `--gitignore` option as of version 2.0.0, released Dec 2021.

https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/CHANGES

Comment: I can't get it to work. Does it work for anyone?

Comment: @lindhe It works for me. tree v2.1.1 on Mac & Linux. Possibly an old version of tree?

Comment: Or maybe I didn't try in the same directory as the `.gitignore`. I'm used for it to work in subdirectories too, but apparently not so with `tree --gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a modification of [@adigitoleo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/632196/185953) that also lists hidden files (for example, files starting with '.' on Unix) tracked by Git:

```bsh
# --files : Print files that would be searched
# --hidden : Print files starting with '.'
# --ignore : Respect .gitignore
# --glob '!.git/' : ignore .git/ directory
tree-git-seen() {
    rg --files --hidden --ignore --glob '!.git/' "$@" \
    | tree --fromfile -a
}
```

Comment: Pending edit: I rearranged the parameters to make it more readable. The previous arrangement `--ignore --hidden --files` reads like it does the the exact opposite!